# How can I display that date and time of postings?

Tags: support

I'd like postings (and ideally comments) to show date and time instead of '5 hours ago' or '10 days ago'.  I've looked for a settings page without success, and also done various searches on the help page.  Surely this must be possible somehow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hover over the `5 hours ago` and you'll see

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Any way to set the time zone, or to make it visible without hovering?  (I tend to avoid using the mouse if I can.)

Comment: I really don't know anything about that. I found it by accident too :)

Comment: You may be interested in [Display absolute timestamps (in local time)](http://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time), a userscript on StackApps.

Answer (score 5):

There is no option on the site to enable this functionality. However, you *can* do this using userscripts. On Google Chrome, I use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) to install and manage userscripts. Firefox users can use Greasemonkey, and there are equivalents for most modern browsers.

The userscript to use is found on StackApps: [Display absolute timestamps (in local time)](https://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time). The hosting link is down, but the author, Kip, has posted the code. This may be copied and pasted into a new userscript in a userscript manager of your choice.

Here is a look at the differences in the display with/without the script running:

[image]